# How To Reset the isChecked property of checkbox in datatemplate of a listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, checkbox

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
        <ToggleButton Name="buttonEditListBoxItem" 
                      Content="Edit" 
                      IsChecked="False"
                      Click="buttonEditListBoxItem_Click"></ToggleButton>
        <ListBox  Name="ListBoxTriggers" 
             SelectedValuePath="TriggerId" 
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
             SelectionChanged="Triggers_SelectionChanged"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>  <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=buttonEditListBoxItem, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="checkBoxTriggers" ></CheckBox>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GlassButton}" 
                        Uid="{Binding Path=TriggerId}" 
                        Margin="5"
                       x:Name="ButtonTrigger"
                       GotFocus="ButtonTrigger_GotFocus"
                      >
                            <Button.Content>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Justify"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="6"   Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate> </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I have a data template for a Listbox which has a button and a checkbox .There is a ToggleButton outside the listbox which decides the visbility of the checkboxes.
The problem is if i have clicked on the ToggleButton  and the checkboxes are visible and i have checked some checkboxes when i click the ToggleButton  again the checkboxes are hidden but I want the checkboxes to reset; as in when they are visible again i want none of the checkboxes clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a handler for the IsVisibleChanged event of the CheckBox:

```
IsVisibleChanged="checkBoxTriggers_IsVisibleChanged"
```

and in the handles clear the IsChecked flag:

```
private void checkBoxTriggers_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

  if (!cb.IsVisible) 
    cb.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Probably same effect could be achieved by using a trigger similar to this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="false">
  <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="false" />
</Trigger>
```